# Covering an 8x8 board with L and O Tetromino

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, puzzle, combinatorial-geometry, tiling

I solved a puzzle about proving that if a rectangular board can be covered by L-Tetrominoes then the number of squares must be a multiple of 8.
I based the solution on a colored board (like a chessboard) and 2 types of L-Tetrominoes
Either:

```
 _____
|BLACK|    
|WHITE|_______  
|BLACK| WHITE|
--------------
```

or

```
 _____
|WHITE|    
|BLACK|_______  
|WHITE|BLACK |
--------------
```

The follow up puzzle is:
Prove that an 8x8 board can **not** be covered with 1 O-Tetromino and 15 L-Tetrominoes.
The O-Tetromino is:

```
 ____ ____
|    |    |    
|----+----|    
|____|____|
```

I thought of the following proof:

If I use 1 O-Tetromino then there remains a board of 8x8-4 = 60 squares.
60 is not a multiple of 8 and we have already shown that for a board to be covered with L-Tetrominoes must be a multiple of 8. Therefore the 8x8 board can not be covered with 1 O-Tetromino and 15 L-Tetrominoes

Is this proof valid? It seems to informal also in relation to the approach I followed to prove that the L-Tetrominoes cover a board of x8
If it is not, then how can I prove it?

Comment: However, after placing the O-Tetromino, the board is no longer considered *rectangular*, which is the basis for the previous problem.

Comment: @player3236: But the proof for that was based on the number of squares and not the shape.

Comment: The shape is important: the L-Tetromino itself is composed of $4$ squares, which is not a multiple of $8$.

Comment: @Jim:  If it was just based on the number of squares, you may be able to go back to the proof and restate the result in a way you can use here.  It is not as simple as the number of squares because one L tetromino can cover the four square region of one L tetromino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have stated the earlier conclusion correctly, the proof does not work because the board less the O tetromino is not rectangular.

A simpler proof that you need an even number of tetrominos to cover a rectangle comes from coloring the board with alternate black and white stripes instead of the traditional checkerboard.  With that coloring, each L tetromino covers three squares of one color and one square of the other.  An odd number of L tetrominos cannot color an equal number of black and white squares.  Now once you note that the O tetromino covers two squares of each coloring, you can just use the count of squares instead of the shape of the board to conclude that $15$ L tetrominos cannot cover what is left.

Comment: If I use the coloring you mention, and each L-tetrominoes add 3 whites and 1 black then 15 L-tetrominoes cover 3*15=45 whites but the total whites are 32. Does this already prove that it is not possible? If so why is the O-tetromino even required at all?

Comment: Using my coloring some of the L tetrominos cover 3 black and 1 white.  The point is that you can't cover $60$ squares that are $30$ of each color with $15$ L tetrominos.  The O was part of the original problem.  If you want to cover the whole board with $16$ tetrominoes it is easy.

Comment: Since the example puzzles that preceded this, colored the tetrominoes, I mapped your approach to the color of the tetrominoes too. I.e. The top and the 2 in the bottom white and the second from the top blacked. This matches the chessboard in the color you specified. This way I counted 45 white covered hence contradiction. Is this thought process correct?

Comment: Yes you are right that the O was part of the original problem but problems sometimes include elements that are not really required to the solution to confuse the reader. Is this the case here?

Comment: No.  As I said in my last comment, if the O tetromino is not used, you can cover the whole board easily.  The O is necessary to make the number of white squares not a multiple of $4$ so that the L tetrominos cannot cover it.

Comment: I think I got it: There are 2 types of L-Tetrominoes. One type with 3 white and 1 black squares. And another with 1 white and 3 black squares. In order to cover and equal number of black and white squares we need to have an even number i.e. half and half of each type. But we have an odd number i.e. 15. This mean either 3 extra white or 3 extra black. The O-Tetromino provides either 2 white or 2 black hence it is still short of covering the board. Is my understanding correct? If I am messing this up, would it be possible to elaborate more on the details of the reasoning?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct

Comment: Thank you for your help. One last question, what is the intuition behind the approach of the solution? Is there some formulaic way or pattern to notice so that one can think about coloring that way? I was stuck completely with the chessboard colors and coloring the L-Tetrominoes 2-white/2black which was a dead end of course

Comment: Clever colorings are a staple of these proofs.  You want to find a coloring that forces the covering of a useful number of squares of each color.  As you say, the standard chessboard one doesn't help here.  Stripes are probably the next most common.  Another would be the same number of colors as squares in the tile, here $4$, arranged RBGWRBGWRBGW in one row, then shifted by one for the next row so that each color makes diagonals.  It depends on the shape of the tiles you are working with.

Comment: `Clever colorings are a staple of these proofs` but what is/was the thought process to break this down to colors? Is there some pattern in how to approach the solution?

Comment: Many proofs of impossibility of tilings rely on them.  If you read some, you see how they work.  Sometimes the coloring is easy to find, sometimes hard.  I don't think it is any different from other proofs in math where you don't have an algorithm.  You have to play with things until you find something that works.  Having read a lot of proofs can help your intuition about what to try.